# Why does wp_get_attachment_image_src return the wrong size, when the correct size exists?

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic, post-thumbnails

I have the following sizes registered, which I have verified with Regenerate Thumbnails.

```
thumbnail => 185x125 (crop)
shop_thumbnail => 150x62 (crop)
alm-thumbnail => 150x150 (crop)
```

Using the following code, I get the wrong size:

```
$test = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'shop_thumbnail' );
/*
$test = array(
  "http://.../2018/02/underwear-150x150.png",
   62,
   62
)
*/
```

But if I use this function to get metadata, the custom size is clearly defined...

```
$test = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
/*
$test = array(
  ["width"]=> int(177)
  ["height"]=> int(436)
  ["file"]=> string(21) "2018/02/underwear.png"
  ["sizes"]=> array(
"thumbnail"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["file"]=> string(21) "underwear-177x125.png"
      ["width"]=> int(177)
      ["height"]=> int(125)
      ["mime-type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
    }
// ...some other sizes
    ["shop_thumbnail"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["file"]=> string(20) "underwear-150x62.png"
      ["width"]=> int(150)
      ["height"]=> int(62)
      ["mime-type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
    }
)
```

As you can see, shop_thumbnail does exist in the second example but isn't what is being returned in the first example. I did check to make sure the file 150x62 exists, and it does.

Why is wp_get_attachment_image_src returning the wrong size? It appears to be using alm-thumbnail even though ajax load more isn't even used on this page.

Lots of "possible duplicates" say I need to define $content_width, but I couldn't get that to fix the problem.

**Update:** Changing 'shop_thumbnail' to `array(150, 62)` works, but that's not ideal since shop_thumbnail is used throughout WooCommerce templates. I'd still like to figure this out.

Comment: Why are you changing thumbnail image size from 150x150 to 185x125 instead of introducing a new size? `thumbnail` is a wordpress default image-size.

Comment: Is this a woocommerce site?

Comment: @admcfajn Because the theme I'm building doesn't use 150x150 but isn't that irrelevant?

Comment: @BenB Yeah it is woocommerce

Comment: @admcfajn You can edit the thumbnail size in settings. It's perfectly reasonable to change it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie & Radley thought we might be dealing with weirdness  from `add_image_size('thumbnail', 185, 125)` being used without `function doThis($sizes) { unset( $sizes['thumbnail']); return $sizes; } add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'doThis');`.  ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90877/filter-what-image-sizes-get-generated ... if we're using `add_image_size('thumbnail', 185, 125, true)` then we should call it something else, like `add_image_size('wide_thumbnail', 185, 125, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
```

This seems to be the default function to get a product thumbnail, as you could see in [wc code base](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail.html#924-938) 
By default it will return woocommerce_thumbnail but seems like it accepts other sizes in the first parameter.